# How to allow a page break in split equations?

Tags: equations, numbering, page-breaking

I'm trying to break an equation onto the next page. The `split` environment doesn't let me page break. I know that I can achieve a page break using the `align*` environment from the package `amsmath`, however, I can't put one equation tag for the whole block. I know that it is possible to add one tag to an equation but if there is an even number of them, the tag must be in the middle, between equations. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where would the tag go, if the equation splits across a page?  What if it splits at the natural tag location?

Comment: Well, in this case I assume it will have to take another location? What is the accepted location in this case?

Comment: I have no idea, though in such cases, I would tend to tag the final line of the equation.  And that is part of the confusion regarding the question...how would you prefer it to behave?

Comment: I understand your point of view - I thought that they would put it in the middle or somewhere near the middle but if it is accepted to put it on the last line then I presume that it would be better to do so

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but does adding `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the preamble (or locally using `\begin{group}\allowdisplaybreaks ... \end{group}`) do what you want?

Comment: @SandyG from what I've read, `\allowdisplaybreaks` doesn't work with `split`. It works with `align*`, however, the block is not numbered and when `align` is used - all lines have a tag. When I use `split` environment, there is one number for the whole block. So I was trying to page break an equation that I split in multiple lines an number it with one tag in the middle