# How to allow latex to split equation between pages?

Tags: equations, page-breaking, subequations

I have an extremely long equation using subequations, similar to the below, except that it has many many constraints.  latex starting a new page at the beginning of the equation.  However, I'd prefer if it started the equation, and then allowed for a pagebreak in between some of the constraints.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations} \label{eq:my_eq}
\begin{alignat}{2}
& \min_{x, w,b}   && \gamma   \label{eq:obj}          \\
& &  & \text{s.t. } x \le 1   \label{eq:constr_1}.    \\
& &  & \text{s.t. } 0 \le w \le 1 \label{eq:constr_2} \\
& &  & \text{s.t. } x \ge 0 \label{eq:constr_3}.      \\
& &  & \text{s.t. } 0 \le b \le 1 \label{eq:constr_4}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

I saw the question here: [Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/), but the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` didn't change anything for me.  Does anyone know another way around this?

I also saw this question: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625456/`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625456/%60), although I'm not in a `split` environment so it didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your claim that the you can't get page breaks within the `alignat{2}` environment is a bit puzzling. For sure, check what happens if you insert the instruction `\setlength\textheight{3mm}` immediately before `\begin{document}` and re-run LaTeX: You should be getting the 5-line equation spread out over 5 pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I add to your code snipped missed part (documentclass, package `amsmath`), then works as expected: equation break between two pages. So, please extend your code snipped to complete small document, which we can test as it is and which reproduce your problem!

Comment: @Zarko - While you were posting your comment, I edited the OP's sample code and added `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath}` to make the code minimally compilable. :-)

Comment: @Mico, thank you for help to OP, but this not reproduce OP problem (if it really exist). So I like that he show MWE, which reproduce problem about which he complain.

Comment: @Zarko - You're right.